# How to keep general internet traffic off Windows 2008 R2 VPN and only handle VPN traffic?

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, vpn, routing

I just set up a Windows Server 2008 R2 VPN that uses SSTP, and everything works wonderfully. Connection is fast, and setup is EXTREMELY simple for domain users with Vista and Windows 7.

The only problem is that ALL traffic is getting routed through the VPN connection. Folks at home or on networks outside our office network have faster Internet connections, but because they're being routed through our office connection, they are limited by that connection. Further, that means that the office connection is being shared by all users while connected.

I would like to know how to route non-office-network related traffic through the local adapters rather than on the VPN. Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [CMAK](http://www.isaserver.org/img/upl/vpnkitbeta2/cmak.htm) to create a connectoid that has the option to not use the remote connection as the default gateway. Deploy that connectoid to your users. If you can't deploy the connectoid, simply have your users edit the properties of the connection thusly: Properties >> Networking Tab >> TCP/IP v4 properties >> Advanced >> Disable "Use default gateway on remote network". Works like a charm.

Comment: Client settings worked like a charm. The Connectoid works a little differently in 2008 R2, but I will be looking to do that as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The general term for this is "split tunneling". I have extensive experience with Cisco IPsec vpn as well as OpenVPN. Both of these easily support split tunneling. Having never worked with Windows VPN, I have no idea if (or how) it supports split tunnelling.

I googled around a bit and it seems as if there may be some settings on the client side that tell the client to not use the remote gateway for all traffic. Lacking a windows box, though, I can't verify that at the moment. Perhaps that might be enough information to get you pointed in the right direction, though.